# Comparable< type > array VS Comparable array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I have a `Point` class which implements `Comparable`.
I want to do `Point f = arr[first];`

Now , I have read that using raw type `Comparable` etc is bad.
So , If i make `arr[]` of type `Comparable<Point>[]` instead of `Comparable[]` What will i be doing wrong ?

This is stolen code , i loved it and i stole it.

```
private static void sort(Comparable[] a, Point compPoint, int lo, int hi) {
    if (hi <= lo)
        return;
    int lt = lo;
    int gt = hi;
    int i = lo;
    int count = 0;
    Comparator comp = compPoint.SLOPE_ORDER;
    Comparable v = a[lo];
    ArrayList<Point> line = new ArrayList<Point>();
    line.add(compPoint);
    while (i <= gt) {
        int cmp = comp.compare(a[i], v);
        if (cmp < 0)
            exch(a, lt++, i++);
        else if (cmp > 0)
            exch(a, i, gt--);
        else {
            count++;
            line.add((Point) a[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    if (count >= 3) {
        Collections.sort(line, new Comparator<Point>() {
            public int compare(Point v, Point w) {
                return v.compareTo(w);
            }
        });
        for (int j = 0; j < line.size(); j++) {
            if (j == line.size() - 1)
                StdOut.println(line.get(j).toString());
            else
                StdOut.print(line.get(j).toString()
                    + " -> ");
        }

        line.get(0).drawTo(line.get(line.size() - 1));
    }

    sort(a, compPoint, lo, lt - 1);
    sort(a, compPoint, gt + 1, hi);
}



private static void exch(Comparable[] a, int v, int w) {
    Comparable tmp = a[v];
    a[v] = a[w];
    a[w] = tmp;
}
```

I want to know if there is a better way than having raw type Comparable.

Comment: Why can't you write a `Comparator`?

Comment: Why don't you just make it of type `Point[]`?

Comment: "stolen" sounds too wrong :/ at least provide some credits...

Comment: I edited in some code , would be kind of you guys if you could see it.
@A4L : well , i took it without permission , and who knows , the author might be seeing this post and going like %$#%$#!

Comment: The guy here: https://github.com/arhangeldim/coursera/blob/master/Fast.java ?

Comment: thats him... Thanks for posting him here. :) me too drowsy ... barely keeping my eyes open to see the replies i get here.... :/

Answer (score 3):

As it is now, you could call it like this:

```
String[] array = {"a", "b"};
sort(array, point, 1, 2);
```

Clearly this is ridiculous. Comparing a String with a point is, well pointless.

It seems that the code in the method would work for any comparable type. Consider changing the signature to thus:

```
private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(T[] a, T comp, int lo, int hi) {
```

Comment: That should actually be `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`, such that a class defined as `BetterPoint extends Point` can be used

Comment: @Eric not exactly. BetterPoint could still be used. Using super bound means you could have an array of Point and a super class of Point. Subclass instances can always be used instead of named classes - that's the backbone of OO.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to cast T[] to Point[] properly (if at all thats needed). Also , since `comp` is now of type T instead of Point , what is the best way to cast it into `Point` ? I tried out `Comparator<Point> comp = ((Point) ref).SLOPE_ORDER;` ... is that ok ?

Comment: It looked at first that it didn't need to be a Point, but if it does, just make the array `Comparable<Point>[]` and make that the only change

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with refactoring the code to use generics. It seems that this method is used only for `Point`s so I'd go with `Point[]` instead of `Comparable<Point>[]`. From what I see you'll have also to refactor the class [Point](https://github.com/arhangeldim/coursera/blob/master/Point.java) and the `compare` method of the  Comaprator `SLOPE_ORDER` in it.

If you are permitted, just download all the code and refactor it. If it compiles everything will be fine, then this is the point of java generics: it helps at compile time do nothing wrong. At runtime it's all raw anyways due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a bunch of things you should do:

- `class Point implements Comparable` should become `class Point implements Comparable<Point>`
- `Comparator` should become `Comparator<Point>`
- Replace `Comparable[]` with `Point[]` - if you're going to cast the elements to `Point`s, you may as well declare them as points
- Replace

  ```
  Collections.sort(line, new Comparator<Point>() {
      public int compare(Point v, Point w) {
          return v.compareTo(w);
      }
  });
  ```

  with the less redundant

  ```
  Collections.sort(line);
  ```